# Autolayout Xcode : Preview displaying wrong output of Autolayout with respect to diff devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, preview

I am using **Xcode 10.1**

Please see this screenshot.

[image]

In ViewController, I take "Table view" and add a "cell".

In the cell, I just added an **image view** which I Have highlighted in Green color. I set their constraints as per screenshot attached.

Now the problem is :

I have set the constraints for **iPhone SE** and when I am trying to see it's output for **iPhone 8**, it is displaying the wrong preview of the auto layout.

When I run it on the device, it shows the expected result. See below image.

[image]

is there a bug in Xcode Preview? or any other settings we do need to make in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Preview is just for reference it don't shows actual screen look always so don't rely on it too much.